# Get sum total using mongodb c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following mongodb query that works fine in the shell

```
db.twitterStats.aggregate([{$group:{_id:0,total:{$sum:"$TwitterHashTagCount"}}},{"$project":{"_id":0,"total":1}}])
```

I am trying to do the same thing in c# using mongodb c# driver I have following code so far:

```
public IMongoCollection<Stat> Stats
    {
        get { return _database.GetCollection<Stat>(StatsCollectionName); }
    }

 var agg = Stats.Aggregate()
            .Group("{_id:0,total:{$sum:'$TwitterHashTagCount'}}")
            .Project("{\"_id\":0,'total':1}");
```

From the agg object how do I actually get the value total?

Regards

Ismail

Answer (score 0):

So in answer to my own question, with a bit of tinkering I now have

```
            var agg = Stats.Aggregate<Stat>()
                        .Group(new BsonDocument 
                                    { 
                                        { "_id", 0
                                        }, 
                                        { 
                                            "total", new BsonDocument 
                                                         { 
                                                             { 
                                                                 "$sum", "$TwitterHashTagCount" 
                                                             } 
                                                         } 
                                        } 
                                    })
                        .Project(new BsonDocument 
                                    { 
                                        {"_id", 0},                            
                                        {"total", 1}, 
                                    });

        var doc = agg.SingleAsync();

        BsonDocument result = doc.Result;

        return result.GetValue("total").AsInt32;
```

Which works.